# How to interpret the output of nmap "vulners"

Tags: exploit, nmap, vulnerability-scanners

I am trying to judge the security of a web app and I have the sample output below from nmap. But I'm not really sure how to properly interpret it.

Is it merely a printout of all the CVEs for this version of Apache2 (cpe:/a:apache:http_server:2.4.41).

OR does it list only the vulns that are applicable and exploitable on this machine?

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE VERSION
80/tcp  open  http    Apache httpd 2.4.41
|_http-server-header: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
| vulners:
|   cpe:/a:apache:http_server:2.4.41:
|       CVE-2022-31813  7.5     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2022-31813
|       CVE-2022-23943  7.5     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2022-23943
|       CVE-2022-22720  7.5     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2022-22720
|       CVE-2021-44790  7.5     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-44790
|       CVE-2021-39275  7.5     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-39275
|       CVE-2021-26691  7.5     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-26691
|       CVE-2020-11984  7.5     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2020-11984
|       1337DAY-ID-34882        7.5     https://vulners.com/zdt/1337DAY-ID-34882        *EXPLOIT*
|       FDF3DFA1-ED74-5EE2-BF5C-BA752CA34AE8    6.8     https://vulners.com/githubexploit/FDF3DFA1-ED74-5EE2-BF5C-BA752CA34AE8     *EXPLOIT*
|       CVE-2022-22721  6.8     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2022-22721
|       CVE-2021-40438  6.8     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-40438
|       CVE-2020-35452  6.8     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2020-35452
|       8AFB43C5-ABD4-52AD-BB19-24D7884FF2A2    6.8     https://vulners.com/githubexploit/8AFB43C5-ABD4-52AD-BB19-24D7884FF2A2     *EXPLOIT*
|       4810E2D9-AC5F-5B08-BFB3-DDAFA2F63332    6.8     https://vulners.com/githubexploit/4810E2D9-AC5F-5B08-BFB3-DDAFA2F63332     *EXPLOIT*
|       4373C92A-2755-5538-9C91-0469C995AA9B    6.8     https://vulners.com/githubexploit/4373C92A-2755-5538-9C91-0469C995AA9B     *EXPLOIT*
|       0095E929-7573-5E4A-A7FA-F6598A35E8DE    6.8     https://vulners.com/githubexploit/0095E929-7573-5E4A-A7FA-F6598A35E8DE     *EXPLOIT*
|       CVE-2022-28615  6.4     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2022-28615
|       CVE-2021-44224  6.4     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-44224
|       CVE-2020-1927   5.8     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2020-1927
|       CVE-2022-30556  5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2022-30556
|       CVE-2022-30522  5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2022-30522
|       CVE-2022-29404  5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2022-29404
|       CVE-2022-28614  5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2022-28614
|       CVE-2022-26377  5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2022-26377
|       CVE-2022-22719  5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2022-22719
|       CVE-2021-36160  5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-36160
|       CVE-2021-34798  5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-34798
|       CVE-2021-33193  5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-33193
|       CVE-2021-30641  5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-30641
|       CVE-2021-26690  5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-26690
|       CVE-2020-9490   5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2020-9490
|       CVE-2020-1934   5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2020-1934
|       CVE-2020-13950  5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2020-13950
|       CVE-2019-17567  5.0     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2019-17567
|       CVE-2020-11993  4.3     https://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2020-11993
|_      1337DAY-ID-35422        4.3     https://vulners.com/zdt/1337DAY-ID-35422        *EXPLOIT*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help text for the script tells you that it looks up the service version against the vulners.com API. It is simply a version-to-known-CVE mapping.

Comment: With the important caveat that it doesn't take into account the backporting of security patches that Ubuntu does. So in reality, many of the CVEs may not actually be relevant to the *actual* version of Apache that's installed.

Comment: Thanks a mil for the feedback. Any idea if there is a way to filter out the CVEs that the machine is not susceptible to? or will it be a case of having to test each CVE against the machine individually?

Comment: @SonofSam if you want to know what this server is vulnerable to given the applied controls in place, then you need to test the controls.